# Convert an image to a Base64 string on iOS using Phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, base64

I am developing an application on iOS. I am using Phonegap and jQuery Mobile for my application. Currently I am retrieving an image's URI when the user clicks an image or selects it from a gallery using Phonegap and saving the URI locally. I need to submit these images on a server by converting them in a Base64 string. In order to convert them into Base64 I am using the Phonegap-provided example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FileReader Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }
    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }
    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }
    function gotFile(file){
        readDataUrl(file);
        readAsText(file);
    }
    function readDataUrl(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as data URL");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    function readAsText(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as text");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
    function fail(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.error.code);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Read File</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the example, instead of "readme.txt" I am passing a local image URI for testing on the simulator `fileSystem.root.getFile("image.png", null, gotFileEntry, fail);`. However I get the following error:

> Error in error callback : File2 = TypeError:'undefined' is not an object.

I also tried the absolute path for the image but got the same error. I do not understand what can go wrong? Am I missing anything ? I need to crack this ASAP.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your file must be created first, if you're sure that this is the case, you can get access to it by specifying the second argument of getFile methode like this:

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("image.png", {'create' : false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
```

The {'create': false} will tell phonegap to not create the file, which is the default case I think.